# Common issue with php timezone in Joomla 3

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, joomla

I have a custom .php file that creates new Joomla articles with the desirable content. So, in my php script I have a connection to database, to `jos_content` table in order to create new articles.

One of the columns in SQL query is "created" and the value is a php variable $d (it is date).

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Belgrade");
$d = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

In GLOBAL CONFIGURATION > SERVER in Joomla 3, I set up a timezone to be also Belgrade.

Additionaly, I created a `php.ini` file in my root directory on server and add line of code of the particluar timezone

```
date.timezone = "Europe/Belgrade"
```

And after all this effort, the timezone is not applying. It is +2 again and obviously I have to change somewhere else, something else.

*If I set up H:i:s to be 00:00:00 I got the result that my article will be published on today's date but at 02:00:00.*

What am I missing?

Comment: Use apache? You pointed to the new php.ini? Try restarting apache.

Comment: How can I restart apache, my site is online it is not localhost. Is there a way to restart it? Because, the resellers sometimes don't give those permissions. Are you sure the problem is in apache restart?

Comment: So put this function PHP `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Belgrade');` at the beginning of your page and check.

Comment: In the back end of Joomla you can view the system information, including all the settings populated for PHP, much like viewing the results of phpinfi().  Check our what Joomla considers the default timezone to verify your settings are configured properly.  Once you confirm we can move in to other possibilities.

Comment: Yes. I changed it there. In System info in my Global configuration, the local timezone is changed to Europe/Belgrade. No luck with that :( The default Timezone is UTC, and that is obviously the problem, but I changed local one in Global Configuration.

Comment: You're not trying to store in anything but UTC are you?